# rails 4.2 + mssql 2012+ tiny_tds + freetds + activerecord-sqlserver-adapter at windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sql-server-2012, freetds, tiny-tds

The problem is my app and my sql server instance are both on `windows`.

I used `ruby-odbc` and that works fine, but I have some trouble with dates and `utf-8` values. I realized I have to use **tiny_tds** with `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`, but **tiny_tds** works with **freetds**.

How can I install and use **freetds** on windows ?

Answer (score 0):

FreeTDS provides an up-to-date Windows version on SourceForge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/

Good luck!